# Windows SSL Certificate access issue

Tags: windows-7, ssl-certificate

There seems to be something going on with my Windows 7 installation's SSL Certificate store, and I'm not quite sure how to resolve it. The full issue is described in the question and replies in [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33264502/windowserror-error-5-access-is-denied-using-urllib2).

Tintin provided the following summary of the issue:

> so, there is something wrong with the windows CA -certification
>   authority store (certmgr:Intermediate Certification Authorities) that
>   makes WINAPI::CertOpenSystemStore fail for CA. I'd suggest to launch
>   certmgr, navigate to Intermediate Certification Authorities and go
>   through that list of cerficates or check with microsoft support as it
>   seems like there is something messed up there. Anyway, can check
>   whether print enum_certificates(u"CA") also raises an error.

I'm not quite sure how to determine if there's something wrong in the certificates, or how to proceed, in general. Any assistance in resolving the issue would be appreciated.

Comment: If you can open CA store by using `certmgr.msc` and with `certutil -user -store CA`, then the issue is related to Python, not to Windows. Does, these tool work for you?

Comment: @CryptoGuy - Thanks, CryptoGuy - running `certutil -user -store CA` shows a list of certificates. The only thing there that seems off, is that the data for each certificate ends with the lines: `No key provider information` and `Cannot find the certificate and private key for decryption.` I'm not quite sure what to look for under `certmgr.msc`.

Comment: It looks like, everything with certificate store is ok. Certitil.exe attempts to verify private key if presented. Since these are CA certificates, then no private key is installed. It is expected behavior in your case. In certmgr.msc, you should open Intermediate CAs folder and see if certificate list is available. Based on certutil output, I can suspect that MMC will work as expected and the issue is related to Python.

Comment: @CryptoGuy - indeed, under Intermediate Certificates, I can see the 'Certificate Revocation List' and 'Certificates' folders, and I can view the certificates within those. Alright, I'll investigate whether there's something Python-specific going on. Thank you!

Comment: That's true. If there was an issue with Windows certificate store, you would know about this long before you run your Python application, because too many internal (and external) things rely on certificate store and they would fail altogether.